# DebugElement.query does not work with elements added dynamically to the dom in a spec

Tags: testing, jasmine

I have an app that is using ngx-bootstrap to show a tooltip on mouseover. I want to test that the content, which is dynamically added, shows properly. In order to do this I have a test that looks like this:

```
it(shows the right tooltip', fakeAsync(() => { 
  fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(TooltipDirective))
         .triggerEventHandler('mouseover', null);
  tick();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.tooltip-inner')).nativeElement)
        .toBe('the tooltip text');
}
```

This results in an error that indicates that `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.tooltip-inner'))`: "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null"

If I print out the content of `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement` I get this:

```
<div id="root1" ng-version="5.2.9">
  <my-component>
    <div ng-reflect-tooltip="the tooltip text">
      <img src="images/test.png">
    </div>
    <bs-tooltip-container role="tooltip" class="tooltip in tooltip-right">
      <div class="tooltip-arrow arrow"></div>
      <div class="tooltip-inner">the tooltip text</div>
    </bs-tooltip-container>
  <my-component>
</div>
```

The important take away is that the html exists - it is just not accessible by the `DebugElement.query`.

My current solution to get the spec passing is to change the expect to:

```
expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.textContent.trim())
      .toBe('the tooltip text');
```

This works, but it is a hack that will fall to pieces if I run into a similar situation with multiple tooltips (for example). Has anyone been able to handle this in a better way? Am I not setting this spec up correctly?

Comment: What if you use `document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-inner')` instead?

Comment: That is a great suggestion - I don't think fixture.debugElement is actually part of the document. `document.getElementsByClassName('.tooltip-inner').item(0);` returns `null`. If I use jQuery, I can access it via: `$(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement).find('.tooltip-inner:eq(0)).text();`
I am attempting to get away from jQuery though.

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-inner')`, without the dot.

Comment: Good catch! That was the problem with my test. It is still strange that you can't use DebugElement methods to access the Element details.